# Is there way for label to automatically change when i type from a cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to link `Label1` to a `A1 cell` in which if I change the value of that cell (or any changes from `sheet1`) the `Label1` will automatically change (that doesn't require a button to change it.).

[image]

Comment: What is `Label1`? A label on what?

Comment: @BigBen from the form controls.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Select the label Form Control.
2. In the formula bar, type `=A1` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]